# How far can water travel through garden hose and soaker hose?

Tags: watering, hoses

The back left of our house and back right of our house has water spigets. We want to run a regular hose back left of house to back left of yard, about a 100 feet. That would then connect to a soaker hose that would be 100 feet and cover half of the back property line that will be lined with arborvitaes. The on the back right side of house 100 foot hose would go to back right corner of property and then attach to a soaker hose that would go 100 feet cover the right half of back property line with arbs.

We have a relatively new house with good water pressure and won’t have any other water running when running the hoses. And we can do the left side one day abs right side the next day. And flat surface, if anything going slightly down hill which should help? First question is, will water be able to travel that far? That is I know water can travel 100 feet in a normal house and 100 feet in soaker hose, but is it going to be able to travel 100 feet throug normal and then 100 threw the soaker and water everything evenly? I can run as long as needed if that makes a difference. Also would a smaller or larger diameter soaker hose and or smaller or larger regular hose work best? If no difference I assume should buy which ever hose is cheaper?

Comment: what is the PSI? How many holes did you drill in the home made PVC soaker? Is it a store bought soaker? I dump city water on my garden for an hour once per week, and it hides under the mulch, but then at home I don't get enough water pressure to fill the hose. Water can travel forever like the great oil pipelines if everything is properly sealed with enough pressure

Comment: Just a standard relatively new house and no other water will be running so whichever PSI that typically is. Asking what size diameters to get and if possible so I know what to buy. I can purchase whatever is needed. The wouldn’t be drilling holes, just buying a normal hose and a soaker hose. In past years I attached a 20 foot hose to a 100 foot soaker at the house and that seemed to work fine, so if the 20 foot section being instead a 100 won’t make a difference then only question remains whether I should buy the smallest or largest diameter hoses?

Comment: PSI in haiti is not the same PSI as the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length makes "no" difference it is the elevation that matters. A very long length will reduce maximum flow rate . I use a 100ft hose to sprinkle sometimes and notice no reduced flow . Be sure to use the restricters at the inlet of the soaker hose , standard pressure is too high for some types of soakers. The restricters are typically a plastic disc with about a 1/8 " hole in the center. This limits volume so the pressure in the soaker never reaches the full water pressure.Because you need to limit pressure in the soaker ,it is not necessary to use more than the common 1/2 " regular hose..

Comment: Thank you. You mention not necessary to use more than 1/2in but seems most soakers are 3/8 except for the more expensive ones. Should I get the 1/2in though? Is the difference that it will be able to soak in less time? And where most garden hoses that will feed into it are 5/8 is it fine having 5/8 connect to 1/2? Or should they be the same?

Comment: I was referring to the regular hose for 1/2. Larger is not needed but will work well.